# HTML adding border image via inline style

Tags: html, css

Want to put an image as a border around this text.

```
<p style="border: 10px; border-image: url('8bitdog.jpg'); ">
This is a paragraph
</p>
```

This doesn't work for some reason. Using the most updated version of Chrome so I suspect some kind of syntax error?

Comment: Is your image in the same folder as your web page?

Comment: border-image need number at the end (slice) : `border-image: url('8bitdog.jpg') 10;` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image ... and border need a style `border:10px solid` https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/border

Comment: try `border-image: url('/8bitdog.jpg') 25;`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7uxvhcz2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to style the border. example;

```
<p style="border: 10px solid; border-image: url('8bitdog.jpg'); ">This is a paragraph </p>
```

Comment: Yes what is wrong with border-size? @TemaniAfif just change it to 10px.

Comment: this property doesn't exist ... better try your code before posting

Comment: This change worked but I noticed that my image is  appearing extremely small on the 4 corners of the border (regardless of what I change my border-size to). Is there a value that affects the size of the image or would I have to manually change that in photoshop

Comment: @Ashton try like this, i changed the code. I hope it is helpful.

Comment: @Ashton you are welcome. Happy that it worked. You just missed to add border style which is solid. Otherwise, code was looking good.